# Reducir ancho de input text

Tags: php, yii2

Deseo reducir el ancho de mis input text. Los input ocupan todo el ancho de la página, ¿Cómo puedo reducirlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código con el cual muestro los input text:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <?= $form->field($model, "username")->input("text") ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <?= $form->field($model, "email")->input("email") ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <?= $form->field($model, "password")->input("password") ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <?= $form->field($model, "password_repeat")->input("password") ?>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probá esto:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, "username")->input("text",['style'=>'width:50%']) ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, "email")->input("email",['style'=>'width:50%']) ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, "password")->input("password",['style'=>'width:50%']) ?>   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, "password_repeat")->input("password",['style'=>'width:50%']) ?>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

si estas usando bootstrap no recomiendo cambiar los estilos a menos que sea realmente necesario.
esto se puede solucionar con los valores de las columnas de bootstrap que de hecho lo hacen responsive

ejemplo

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

los valores de los tamaños se pueden adaptar a los distintas pantallas con el uso de los prefijos col-xs- col-md- col-lg etc,

[aca tienes la documentacion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)